# XPath: getting all elements without specific @class or @id name

Tags: xpath, scrapy, xpath-1.0

I am getting really frustrated already. I have tried so many variations and searched for an answer in all existing stackoverflow questions, but it didn't help.

All I need is to get **ALL the text** (**without the @class name 'menu' or without the @id name 'menu'**)
I have tried already these commands:

```
//*[not(descendant-or-self::*[(contains(@id, 'menu')) or (contains(@class, 'menu'))])]/text()[normalize-space()]
```

But whatever I try, I always get back the **all the text even with the elements that I excluded**.

Ps: I am using Scrapy which uses XPATH 1.0

```html
<body>
  <div id="top">
    <div class="topHeader">
      <div class="topHeaderContent">
        <a class="headerLogo" href="/Site/Home.de.html"></a>
        <a class="headerText" href="/Site/Home.de.html"></a>
        <div id="menuSwitch"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="topContent">
      <div id="menuWrapper">
        <nav>
          <ul class="" id="menu"><li class="firstChild"><a class="topItem" href="/Site/Home.de.html">Home</a>     </li>
            <li class="hasChild"><span class="topItem">Produkte</span><ul class=" menuItems"><li class=""><a href="/Site/Managed_Services.de.html">Managed Services</a>             </li>
              <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Video.de.html">VideoServices</a>                </li>
              <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Apps.de.html">Mobile Publishing</a>             </li>
              <li class=""><a href="/Site/Broadcasting.de.html">Broadcasting</a>              </li>
              <li class=""><a href="/Site/Content_Management.de.html">Content Management</a>      </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="hasChild"><span class="topItem">Digital Media Base</span><ul class=" menuItems"><li class=""><a href="/Site.de.html">About DMB</a>           </li>
            <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Quellen.de.html">Quellen</a>            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Video.de.html">Video</a>                </li>
            <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Apps.de.html">Apps</a>          </li>
            <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Web.de.html">Web</a>            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Archiv.de.html">Archiv</a>              </li>
            <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Social_Media.de.html">Social Media</a>          </li>
            <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/statistik.de.html">Statistik</a>                </li>
            <li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Payment.de.html">Payment</a>            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="activeMenu "><a class="topItem" href="/Site/Karriere.de.html">Karriere</a>           </li>
        <li class="hasChild"><span class="topItem">Fake-IT</span><ul class=" menuItems"><li class=""><a href="/Site/About.de.html">About</a>             </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Site/Management.de.html">Management</a>          </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Site/Mission_Statement.de.html">Mission Statement</a>        </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Site/Pressemeldungen.de.html">Pressemeldungen</a>            </li>
          <li class=""><a href="/Site/Referenzen.de.html">Kunden</a>              </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="topSearch">
    <div class="topSearch">
      <form action="/Site/Suchergebnis.html" method="get">
        <form action="/Site/Suchergebnis.html" method="get">
          <input class="searchText" onblur="processSearch(this, &quot;Suchbegriff&quot;, &quot;blur&quot;)" onfocus="processSearch(this,&quot;Suchbegriff&quot;)" type="text" value="Suchbegriff" name="searchTerm" id="searchTerm" />
          <input class="searchSubmit" id="js_searchSubmit" type="submit" name="yt0" />
          <div class="stopFloat">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p> I want to have this text here! </p>
.
.
More elements
.
.
</div>
<p> I want to have this text here! </p>
.
.
More elements
.
.
</body>
```

**I always get this back:**

```
['Home',
 'Produkte',
 'Managed Services',
 'VideoServices',
 'Mobile Publishing',
 'Broadcasting',
 'Content Management',
 'Digital Media Base',
 'About DMB',
 'Quellen',
 'Video',
 'Apps',
 'Web',
 'Archiv',
 'Social Media',
 'Statistik',
 'Payment',
 'Karriere',
 'Fake-IT',
 'About',
 'Management',
 'Mission Statement',
 'Pressemeldungen',
 'Kunden',
 ' I want to have this text here! ',
 ' I want to have this text here! ']
```

**But I need it like that:**

```
[' I want to have this text here! ',
 ' I want to have this text here! ']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This very convoluted xpath 1.0 expression works on your sample html. It would be somewhat simpler in xpath 2.0 and above. But try it on your actual code:

```
 //*[not(descendant-or-self::*[contains(@class,'menu')])]
 [not(descendant-or-self::*[contains(@id,'menu')])]
 [not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class,'menu')])]
 [not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@id,'menu')])]//text()
```

Comment: After days of struggle... You, the king, helped me. It works. It finally works. Thank you so so much!!! 

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you consider the element

`<li class=""><a href="/Site/DMB/Video.de.html">VideoServices</a>                </li>`

it's a descendant-or-self of something, and it doesn't have the relevant id or class attribute, so of course it gets selected.

Perhaps you want `//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[@id='menu' or @class='menu']]`

You wrote "contains" but I'm not sure if you really meant it. A lot of people use `contains()` when they should be using "=".

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate tags through scrapy lxml tree directly as it in this code sample:

```
result = []
for tag in response.css("*"):
    if 'id' not in tag.attrib and 'class' not in tag.attrib and 'href' not in tag.attrib:
        text = tag.css("::text").extract_first("").strip("\n ")
        if text:
            result.append(tag.css("::text").extract_first())
```

As You can see I also excluded tags with`href` attribute as `<a>` tags like this:
`<a href="/Site/DMB/Video.de.html">VideoServices</a>`
dont have `class` and `id` attribute and they technically don't violate your Xpath expression.
So if you are planning to use Xpath selectors - you need to exclude tags with `href` attribute too.